# How to programmatically recreate php yii session?

Tags: php, session, yii

From my application view I need to programmatically logout current user and login another one right after that.

I want to login the second user into his own different CHttpSession (with another sessionID and so on). I need it for a security reasons.

How to implement this in Yii framework ?

Code below

$oSession->destroy();
$oSession->open();

doesn't work as expected..

Comment: Re-create session have to be before any output to client. if you create session, output some data - recreate session will not work. You have to create session, delete session, and recreate session after this output some data. Or you have to use buffer output

Answer (score 5):

looks like you are trying to [impersonate users](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/154/impersonate-users-within-yii-framework/):

1. Create a function in your UserIdentity that would alow you to login as another known user:

   ```
   protected function logInUser($user)
   {
       if($user)
       {
           $this->_user = $user;
           $this->_id=$this->_user->id;
           $this->setState('name', $this->_user->name);
           $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
       }
   }
   ```
2. In your controller, call this function to get the UserIdentity object and then use the Yii's CWebUser login

   ```
   $ui = null;
   $user = User::model()->findByPk($userId);
   if($user)
   {   
       $ui = new UserIdentity($user->email, "");
       $ui->logInUser($user);
   }
   Yii::app()->user->login($ui, 0);
   ```

Remember to protect this controller's action from non authorized users.

Answer (score 1):

A possible tricky way (tested):

```
session_unset();
Yii::app()->user->id = $the_new_id;
```

When the above code is executed, nothing visible happens on the page so you may want to redirect the browser:

```
$this->redirect('somewhere');
```

Upon the next page load, the user with the $the_new_id will be logged in